# Structured referenced table formula with filtered rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't find the solution to this. Excel table with 3 Columns:

**[#ID]** -> counter of rows

**[value]** -> just a nunch of positives a negatives numbers

**[negative]** -> 1 when value column is negative 0 when positive and cumulating negative streak

Formulas

```
[#ID] = ROW()-ROW(['# ID])+1
[negative] = IF([@['# ID]]=1,IF([@value]<0,1,0),IF([@value]<0,1+OFFSET([@negative],-1,0)),0))
```

How can keep this working when filtering some rows?

**Without filter**

[image]

**With filter**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Table` starts at row 3 or higher try this formula:

```
= IF( [@value] >= 0, 0,
IF( [@['# ID]] = 1, 1,
SUM( 1, OFFSET( [@negative],
IF( SUBTOTAL( 9, C2:C$3 ) = SUBTOTAL( 9, C$3:C3 ),  -2, -1 ), 0 ) ) ) )
```

[image]

Suggest to see the following pages for additional information about the functions used:
[Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188)
[SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939)
[OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)

Comment: Sorry, definitely is not running properly. Column [# ID] should count visible rows, 10,11 not 10, 12. Looking for another solution. Best regards.

Comment: Well, that's not what you have in your expected results! (not earlier, not now) You had changed the requirements, you should acknowledge that.

Comment: Yes!, sorry!, maybe i had to explain the problem better. I wait for solution while i am trying to solve it. Thanks EEM.

Comment: As mentioned the original question was solved by this answer, after which you inserted substantial changes to the original question. I suggest to edit back the original question, accept the answer and post a new question with the new requirements, this time make sure to include at once all the requirements. BTW I already have the answer to the new question.

Comment: Yes you are right EEM, done!. Thank you so much. Posted a new one.